# error in file upload with PHP

Tags: php, html

I got this PHP Code:

```
SESSION_start();

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if(!$conn) die("Cannot connect to the database server: <br />
    ".mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db("tsismics", $conn);
if(!$db) die("Cannot connect to the database: <br />
    ".mysql_error());

 $userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
 $dir = $userId."/".$_FILES['profpic']['name'];
 $filename = $_FILES['profpic']['name'];

 $target = "profile_pictures/".$userId."/";
 echo $target;

 mysql_query("UPDATE users SET photo=\"$dir\" WHERE userId=$userId", $conn);

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profpic']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
     echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['profpic']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 
     echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 }
```

And this is my HTML block:

```
<form method="POST" action="upload-prof-pic.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" value="upload profile pic" name="profpic"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="prof-pic-submit"> 
</form>
```

When uploading, it creates a file with the userId as the filename and without any extensions, in the folder: profile_pictures

---

I forgot to post this.. It has this 2 errors:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(profile_pictures/1/3.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\project\upload-prof-pic.php on line 22

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php2070.tmp' to 'profile_pictures/1/3.png' in C:\wamp\www\project\upload-prof-pic.php on line 22

Comment: `$target = "profile_pictures/".$userId."/";` that's exactly what you tell it to do.

Comment: `$target = "profile_pictures/".$userId."/".$filename;`

Comment: you need to extract and add ext to $target

Comment: please try to echo what you run as query in your case this must look like this : echo "UPDATE users SET photo=\"$dir\" WHERE userId=$userId";

Then tell me the result :)

Comment: @LastBreath
Here's the echo:
UPDATE users SET photo="1/3.png" WHERE userId=1

Comment: as you told us your problems that the file is uploaded without extension to the profile_pictures but you don't tell us what is the name of the file after uploading then before all this are your sure that a folder have name as your user id exists and also have access privileges ? pleas clear this point so i can give you maximum help :)

Comment: @user2087532 : As i told you the error you have posted early show that the folder 1 doesn't exist or at least doesn't have privilege to uploaded into so i think that you must check if it is not exist then if it is the case create it and continue to the uploading process . Hope that this will solve your problem :)

Comment: THERE!!! HAHAHA. I thought that PHP automatically creates a sub folder when it's not existing on the directory. I don't have a folder named "1" and it's saving unto profile_pictures/1/photo.png THANKS!

Follow-up question. How do I create a folder in PHP?

Comment: please @user2087532 when you are talking in the comment with someone use @[username] as i am using because if you don't use that this user will not notified by a message on his inbox :)

As i can see you from 7 minutes ask me about creating folder but now and in a chance i read your comment so please always use this technique to notify the user that you have asked him something :)

I hope that i can give you any help every time you need and i think this time is too late because "Khaled Mahmud Tuhin" has answered on your question :)

Answer (score 2):

Oh also note one thing (based on your updated question)  since you are trying to store every pic in a new directory that is named after the user id, you need to create that directory as well and obviously have write permissions.

[mkdir](http://php.net/mkdir)

```
$target = "profile_pictures/".$userId."/";
```

should be

```
$target = "profile_pictures/".$userId."/".$filename;
```

Oh, still using that famous `mysql_*` api?

Comment: changed the $target value. Still has errors

Comment: And what is the description of remaining errors

Answer (score 1):

You need :

1. [to make the folder if it doesn't exist](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).
2. [to give it enough privilege to write into it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php).
3. [to use move_uploaded_file properly](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). (path to file parameter and not folder)
4. [to stop using mysql_ functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) (see the red rectangle?)

example :

```
session_start();

if(!empty($_FILES['profpic'])){
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if(!$conn) die("Cannot connect to the database server: <br />
    ".mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db("tsismics", $conn);
if(!$db) die("Cannot connect to the database: <br />".mysql_error());

$userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
$filename = $_FILES['profpic']['name'];

$target = "profile_pictures/".$userId.'/'.$filename;
echo $target;

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET photo=\"$dir\" WHERE userId=$userId", $conn);
if(!file_exists("profile_pictures/".$userId)){
   mkdir("profile_pictures/".$userId, 700);
}
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profpic']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
     echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['profpic']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 
     echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 }
}
```

Comment: lol, red triangle, not `rectangle` :)

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ I was talking about the box containing the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is it or if its valid, but try changing `SESSION_start();` to `session_start();`

it looks like you might want to remove /'s or even better create a md5 of the time/file name so profile_pictures/1/3.png is looking for profile_pictures/1 as a dir

using something like this might work

```
$file = md5($_FILES['profpic']['name'] . microtime(true)) . "." . pathinfo($_FILES['profpic']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

should give you something like `79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4.png` the extension is preserved by using pathinfo()

**EDIT:**
looking over your question again the file isn't what's giving you `/1` as a folder. I'd  recommend having all profile avatars in one folder instead of each user having a folder with one file in it. Change the following line

```
$target = "profile_pictures/".$userId."/";
```

to

```
$target = "profile_pictures/". $_FILES['profpic']['name'];
#OR
$target = "profile_pictures/" . $file;#if using md5 as above
```

and I'd still advise to use the md5 as stated above to overcome same file name uploads

Comment: still has error when changing all to lowercase

Comment: you might have to relogin to get session variables if other pages insert session data. does `var_dump($_SESSION)` produce what should be in the session?

Comment: Yep, it has the correct data when dumped

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to create the folder or directory and upload the file together. 
in that case, i will suggest you to execute this Command first:

```
mkdir("profile_pictures/".$userId , 700);
```

to create the directory before uploading the file.

Hope there will be no problem...

Answer (score 0):

As i told you the error you have posted early show that the folder "1" doesn't exist or at least doesn't have privilege to uploaded into so i think that you must check if it is not exist then if it is the case create it then change its privileges to suitable privilage using `chmod` and continue to the uploading process . Hope that this will solve your problem :)